# Ajax calls going multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have written a code in *Javascript* in which I have attached an input type submit to a `form`. On form submit the listener gets called.

The problem is that on when I click the button once, one ajax call occurs. When I click it again two calls occur while only one call should occur on each click. Similarly on clicking 3 times 3 calls occur and so on...(the calls get increasing). If I refresh the page then the number gets reset. I have tried everything but I had no luck. If anyone found out what is wrong here it would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

*javascript code:*

```
$('input.create-discounts-quotations').click(function () {

    var discount_quotation_type = $('input.quotation-discount-type').val();

    if (discount_quotation_type == "value") {

        var total = $('input.discount-input-quotation').val();
        var discounted_price = product_price - total;
        $('#final_discounted_amount').val(discounted_price);

        $("table.product-response-table tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).index() + 1;
            var td = $(this).find('td.quotation-response-discounts');

            $(td).each(function () {
                $(this).html(total);
            });
        });
        $("table.product-response-table tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).index() + 1;
            var td = $(this).find('td.product_final_price_discounted');

            $(td).each(function () {
                $(this).html(discounted_price);
            });
        });
        var form1 = $('form#quotation_discount_update_form');
        form1.on("submit", function (e) {
            var form_data1 = form1.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form1.attr('action'),
                data: form_data1,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.quotation-discount-status-update').empty();
                    $('.quotation-discount-status-update').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Discount Added</div>');
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
    if (discount_quotation_type == "percentage") {
        var total = $('input.discount-input-quotation').val();
        var temp_first = product_price;
        var temp1 = total / 100;
        var temp2 = temp1 * product_price;
        var discounted_price = product_price - temp2;
        $('#final_discounted_amount').val(discounted_price);

        $("table.product-response-table tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).index() + 1;
            var td = $(this).find('td.quotation-response-discounts');

            $(td).each(function () {
                $(this).html(total);
            });
        });
        $("table.product-response-table tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this).index() + 1;
            var td = $(this).find('td.product_final_price_discounted');

            $(td).each(function () {
                $(this).html(discounted_price);
            });
        });
        var form1 = $('form#quotation_discount_update_form');
        form1.on("submit", function (e) {
            var form_data1 = form1.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: form1.attr('action'),
                data: form_data1,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('.quotation-discount-status-update').empty();
                    $('.quotation-discount-status-update').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Discount Added</div>');
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
    if (discount_quotation_type == "not_selected") {
        $('.quotation-discount-status-update').empty();
        $('.quotation-discount-status-update').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">Discount Method Not Selected</div>');
        return false;
    }
   //        return false;
});
```

Comment: You should avoid creating event bindings inside the event handlers of other bindings.  This is a quick way to create duplicate bindings and run into the issue you are seeing.

Comment: All of your code is wrapped into the `click` handler. Within this handler you have `form1.on("submit", callback);`. So practically every time a `click` happens you bind a new callback to `submit` next to the existing ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happen because every time you click your code will reattach the `submit` event so it will be duplicated in every click.

You should never attach the events inside other events, please put the `submit` event outside of the click event and the code should work, example :

```
var form1 = $('form#quotation_discount_update_form');
form1.on("submit", function (e) {
    var form_data1 = form1.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: form1.attr('action'),
        data: form_data1,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('.quotation-discount-status-update').empty();
            $('.quotation-discount-status-update').append('<div class="alert alert-success">Discount Added</div>');
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Else you have to remove the event handler every time using `.off()`, like :

```
form1.off("submit").on("submit", function (e) {
```